# Exception handling in spring boot with @RestConrollerAdvice

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I Use spring boot 2.0.6.

> I have a mapping like below path:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"})
public class A {
    @PostMapping(value = {"test"}, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getResponse(@RequestBody String message) throws Exception{
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

**It's work when I use below snippet code in the same class( class A)**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"})
public class A {
    @ExceptionHandler({HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> processException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException  exception){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .body("error");
   }

    @PostMapping(value = {"test"}, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getResponse(@RequestBody String message) throws Exception{
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

but when I use a separate class with **RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = A.class) annotation**, it does not work.

```
 @RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = A.class)
 @Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
 public class GlobalExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler({HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> processException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException exception){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .body("error");
    }
}
```

Note: I have another class like B that I want to handle exceptions class B differently.

Comment: You already raised a [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14984) about this and received an answer there. Nothing that I can see has changed. Your `globalExceptionHandler` isn't being called as it's specific to exceptions thrown by classes that are assignable to `A.class` and it's Spring MVC that's throwing the `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`, not your controller.

Comment: ThanQ @AndyWilkinson for your response. suppose I have another class an example `B` and want to handle `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` differently, as example `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("error in class B");` How to separate this two different `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`'s ? Should I implement the exception methods in `A` and `B` classes? can I implement exceptions handling in a separate class? If yes, how?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, could you answer please on the last comment? Because I have the same issue having 2 controllers, 2 `RestControllerAdvice` classes with `assignableTypes=SpecificController.class` and `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` must be handled differently, but `@ExceptionHandlers` methods aren't called in both controllers.
I also noticed that if I don't use `consumes` attribute in my `@RequstMapping`, then it works as expected.

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov I think it'd be better if you asked a new question